# How to get the module tree?

Tags: rust, tree, rust-cargo

I type the command 'cargo tree' at the terminal,but the output does like the below! please help me,thank you!

[the expect output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFEHg.png)

but my output likes this:

```
/Users/antsing/Desktop/rust_project_dir/7_manage_grow_project/restaurant
(base) ➜  restaurant git:(master) ✗ cargo tree                                           
restaurant v0.1.0 (/Users/antsing/Desktop/rust_project_dir/7_manage_grow_project/restaurant)
```

Comment: `cargo tree` outputs the crate tree, not the module tree.

Comment: Just look at your crate's `src/` directory structure. [Almost](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/modules.html#the-path-attribute) all the time it is congruent to your module tree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [cargo-modules](https://github.com/regexident/cargo-modules) for this.

Install the plugin using

```
cargo install cargo-modules
```

and then you can view the tree of modules like that:

```
cargo-modules generate tree --fns
```

Additionally you have the option to also view the types and traits defined in a module as documented [here](https://github.com/regexident/cargo-modules#usage).